# how to traverse inside a xml node and check for an attribute value?

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I have this xml, i took it in xml `a GPathResult object` how can I get `Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition` based on checking with the `field` value as  `OS Name` using groovy xml slurping

```
<client productname="abp">
<machine>
  <env>
   <variable name='ALLUSERSPROFILE' value='C:\Documents and Settings\All Users' />
   <variable name='APPDATA' value='C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data' />
   <variable name='OS' value='Windows_NT' />
   <variable name='COMPUTERNAME' value='AbhishekPC' />
 </env>
 <osinfo>
    <osinfo field='OS Name' information='Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition' />
    <osinfo field='OS Version' information='5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Build 3790' />
    <osinfo field='OS Manufacturer' information='Microsoft Corporation' />
    <osinfo field='OS Configuration' information='Standalone Server' />
    <osinfo field='OS Build Type' information='Multiprocessor Free' />
 </osinfo>
</machine>
</client>
```

Here is the parsing code

```
def file = new File(filepath)
def gpathResult = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

summary.productname=gpathResult.@product.text()
            log.info gpathResult.system.osinfo.osinfo.@field.text()


            System.out.println("HI 1"+gpathResult.machine.environment.variable.@name.text());
            System.out.println("HI 2"+gpathResult.machine.osinfo.osinfo.@field.text());

            if(gpathResult.machine.environment.variable.@name.text().equals("OS"))
            {   
                summary.osname=gpathResult.machine.environment.variable.@value.text()

            }
            if(gpathResult.machine.environment.variable.@name.text().equals("COMPUTERNAME"))
            {   
                summary.hostname=gpathResult.machine.environment.variable.@value.text()
            }
```

Here `HI 1` prints all the environments name attribut values but `HI 2` only prints `HI 2`

here is the snapshot
[image]

here is what solved after i traversed

```
      def    vals1=gpathResult.machine.env.variable.findAll{it.@name=='COMPUTERNAME'}.@value.text()
            println vals1
            csmSummary.hostname=vals1
            def vals2=gpathResult.machine.env.variable.findAll{it.@name=='OS'}.@value.text()
            println vals2
            csmSummary.osname=vals2
```

Comment: Do you have the code you used to parse the xml into the `gpathResult` variable?

Comment: @tim_yates: ya i have, i'll post it in a minute

Comment: How is the `gpathResult` created (`XmlSlurper`, etc?)....that was my question...

Comment: @tim : check now, file path is correct as that is how i get other stuff printed onscreen

Comment: @tim_yates: I was thinking may be i can traverse through all the osinfo, and then check for `field` name if present then print that particular `information` attribute. So how can i traverse this osinfo and check for field attribs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange... if I do this (with Groovy 1.8)

```
def gpathResult = new XmlSlurper().parseText( $/<client productname="abp">
<machine>
  <env>
   <variable name='ALLUSERSPROFILE' value='C:\Documents and Settings\All Users' />
   <variable name='APPDATA' value='C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data' />
   <variable name='OS' value='Windows_NT' />
   <variable name='COMPUTERNAME' value='AbhishekPC' />
 </env>
 <osinfo>
    <osinfo field='OS Name' information='Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition' />
    <osinfo field='OS Version' information='5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Build 3790' />
    <osinfo field='OS Manufacturer' information='Microsoft Corporation' />
    <osinfo field='OS Configuration' information='Standalone Server' />
    <osinfo field='OS Build Type' information='Multiprocessor Free' />
 </osinfo>
</machine>
</client>/$ )

println "HI 1 ${gpathResult.machine.env.variable.@name*.text()}"
println "HI 2 ${gpathResult.machine.osinfo.osinfo.@field*.text()}"
```

it prints out:

```
HI 1 [ALLUSERSPROFILE, APPDATA, OS, COMPUTERNAME]
HI 2 [OS Name, OS Version, OS Manufacturer, OS Configuration, OS Build Type]
```

Can you try that code (assuming you are using 1.8, the latest version of Groovy -- if not, you will need to use `"""` instead of `$/` for the string delimiters, and escape the `\` chars)

[edit] It's probably just because you are using `gpathResult.machine.environment.variable` instead of `gpathResult.machine.env.variable`

to traverse the env nodes, you'd do something like:

```
gpathResult.machine.env.variable.each { node ->
  println "${node.@name.text()} contains ${node.@value.text()}"
}
```

Comment: HI 1 prints correctly, but HI 2 still does not print anything, and in my system its `environment` instead of `env`. Also i am using groovy 1.8, i'll have a snapshot in a minute , check my question

Comment: @Abhishek It must be something you're not telling us then.  As the XML and code do not match, I am guessing that something is wrong with either of them, and you are not posting the correct information here for us to help you.  Was that with you running **exactly** the code above that prints nothing for `HI 2`?

Comment: ok just tell  me how to traverse through  each environment.variable elements, so i can try something else, may be that works

Comment: i copy pasted your `println` statement and here i posted just a bit of the xml, i dont want to reveal parts of xml and node names are also diff, but i am being cautious while editing, that is why  env was environment by mistake

Comment: I think the problem must be that you have `OSinfo` or `osInfo` or something, not `osinfo` as you posted here

Comment: everything is in small caps, i am sure, please tell me how to traverse through each `environment.variable` elements, so i can try something else

Comment: Added an example of iterating through the nodes with `each` to the bottom of my answer